# swift get another user location

Tags: swift, location, mapkit

Hi I was shown an adroid app where parents can see their kids location. I am wondered whether it is possible to do the same in ios. I know you can show your own location but how about showing another person's location. Is it possible? Their kids should not have to do anything the app itself receives child's location

Comment: Can you provide us that android app link so that we can get an idea.

Comment: It is in another language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that would be if you have a database that everyone can access where you store the positions. Take a look at [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html) for the database part.

So basically:

1. Get the position from the user
2. Store the position in the database
3. Get the position from the database
4. Parse the result and add an annotation to your mapview

**Edit**

> If your iOS app must keep monitoring location even while it’s in the
>   background, use the standard location service and specify the location
>   value of the UIBackgroundModes key to continue running in the
>   background and receiving location updates. (In this situation, you
>   should also make sure the location manager’s
>   pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically property is set to YES to help
>   conserve power.) Examples of apps that might need this type of
>   location updating are fitness or turn-by-turn navigation apps

For more information read [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html) by Apple.

Comment: yeah Thanks but I mean like so it should write info in a background and then store in a database. What I mean is my app allowed to take users position in a background?

Comment: @user3428496, check my update I hade added some information about background checking for locations.